# Array Merge with condition

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

Array 1:

```
  [ 
          {
        "product_name": "Redme note 7",
        "quantity": "548.00",
        "purchase_price": "10000.00",
        "product_id": 1
      },
      {
        "product_name": "Redme note 7",
        "quantity": "150.00",
        "purchase_price": "19000.00",
        "product_id": 1
      },
      {
        "product_name": "Fresh Water 5 Litre",
        "quantity": "20.00",
        "purchase_price": "70.00",
        "product_id": 2
      },
      {
        "product_name": "Fresh Water 5 Litre",
        "quantity": "348.00",
        "purchase_price": "80.00",
        "product_id": 2
      },
      {
        "product_name": "Fresh Water 5 Litre",
        "quantity": "1067.00",
        "purchase_price": "800.00",
        "product_id": 2
      }
    ]
```

Array 2:

```
[
  {
    "sales_quantity": "14.00",
    "product_id": 1,
    "purchase_price": "10000.00"
  },
  {
    "sales_quantity": "7.00",
    "product_id": 2,
    "purchase_price": "70.00"
  },
  {
    "sales_quantity": "10.00",
    "product_id": 2,
    "purchase_price": "80.00"
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```
 [ 
          {
            "product_name": "Redme note 7",
            "quantity": "548.00",
            "purchase_price": "10000.00",
            "product_id": 1,
            "sales_quantity":14
          },
          {
            "product_name": "Redme note 7",
            "quantity": "150.00",
            "purchase_price": "19000.00",
            "product_id": 1,
             "sales_quantity":0
          },
          {
            "product_name": "Fresh Water 5 Litre",
            "quantity": "20.00",
            "purchase_price": "70.00",
            "product_id": 2,
            "sales_quantity":14
          },
          {
            "product_name": "Fresh Water 5 Litre",
            "quantity": "348.00",
            "purchase_price": "80.00",
            "product_id": 2,
               "sales_quantity":10
          },
          {
            "product_name": "Fresh Water 5 Litre",
            "quantity": "1067.00",
            "purchase_price": "800.00",
            "product_id": 2,
              "sales_quantity":0
          }
        ]
```

I have tried with following code but it doesn't give me expected output

```
collect(array_merge($products, $sales_products))
              ->groupBy('product_id','purchase_price')
              ->values()
              ->map(fn ($person) => $person->reduce(fn ($acc, $cur) => $acc->merge($cur), collect()))
              ->each(static function ($person) {
                  if (!$person->has('sales_quantity')) {
                      $person->put('sales_quantity', '0');
                  }
              })
        ->toArray();
```

Comment: what is the condition, write about it?

Comment: I want to find the sales_quantity from second array where product_id and sales_price should match with the other array and merge them.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, your grouping logic is only based on `purchase_price`, as the expected result shows.

First, I converted the jsons and then after grouping the items, I set the default value on them using laravel `data_set()` helper function.

```
$arr1 = json_decode($this->json1, true);
$arr2 = json_decode($this->json2, true);
$res  = collect($arr1)
    ->merge($arr2)
    ->groupBy(['purchase_price'])
    ->map(function ($item) {
        $merged=array_merge(...$item);
        data_set($merged,'sales_quantity',0,false);
        return $merged;
    })
->values();

dd($res->toArray());
```

Comment: `product_id` as well as `purchase_price`

Comment: Can you please what is this  `$merged=array_merge(...$item); `   ... here?

Comment: This will merge items in each group

Comment: `array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, object given`
I'm getting this error. 
should i put ... or other array inside the array_merge

Comment: I've no idea about your source code, I think your problem can be solved by a little debugging effort. But the code that I wrote works with the jsons that you posted in the quesrion.